# using python to load docker image zip file without python docker module

Tags: python, docker

Using python3.10.6 and docker 20.10.23, build 7155243 on Ubuntu 22.04. And trying not to use the `docker` module but just `subprocess` to load a docker image

```
def run(params):
    output = subprocess.run(params, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if output.returncode == 0:
        print(output.stdout.decode())
    else:
        print(output.stderr.decode())

run(['sudo', 'docker', 'load', '<', 'PATH/OF/AIMAGE.zip'])
run(['sudo', 'docker', 'run', '-t', '-d', '-v', PATH_REPO + ':/root/windows-mount', 'IMAGE:v3'])
```

I can see the image is loaded fine by using `sudo docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND       CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
96d1f80916ce   IMAGE:v3   "/bin/bash"   53 seconds ago   Up 52 seconds             happy_joliot
```

but the `docker load` always output an error:

```
"docker load" accepts no arguments.
See 'docker load --help'.

Usage:  docker load [OPTIONS]

Load an image from a tar archive or STDIN
[docerapp.py:66]
```

Any suggestion to fix the error?

Comment: Why not use the standard Docker SDK here?  Can you `docker pull` the image from a registry rather than `docker load` it from a manually-copied tar file?  What will happen if `sudo` needs to prompt for a password?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using '<' which means `Load images from STDIN` , '-i' / '--input' meaning `Load images from a file` should be used in the script.

```
run(['sudo', 'docker', 'load', '-i', 'PATH/OF/AIMAGE.zip'])
```